# C++ Sorting vector of structs with const variables alphabetically

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, constants

Hello I wanted to know if it was possible to do a thing like this ?  // THANKS ! :)

```css
struct PET
{ 
 const char* pet;
 const int age;
};

bool Sort(const PET& first, const PET& second)
{
    return first.pet < second.pet;
}

void  Foo(const std::vector<PET> pets)
{ 
  std::sort(pets.begin(), pets.end(), Sort); /* Does not work */
  
  std::cout << pets[0].pet;
  std::cout << pets[0].age;
  
}
```

Comment: No, it's actually not possible, because the elements of your vector are not assignable, due to the `const int` member. Note that the other member is assignable, the `const` doesn't apply to the pointer but only what it points to. Two tasks for you: Firstly, ask yourself if you need this `const` member. Secondly, just keep reading your C++ tutorial, using algorithms like `std::sort()` is usually in the advanced section, but it should be covered there. Further, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, avoid yes/no questions.

Comment: Ah too bad, thanks for your answer :)
And sorry.

Comment: It's also really confusing when you edit your question after there are already comments or answers, so that it becomes completely different from the original question and those comments no longer apply.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @ Ulrich Eckhardt.

You cannot sort the vector as because the elements of your vector are not assignable.

I think, you might have gone confused with usage of `const`.

**There is no need to make the structure variables `const`. The parameter of the custom sort function are generally kept as `const` because they should not be modifiable. This is a pattern which ensures safe coding practice.**

Also, if you are using C++, I would suggest to use std::string instead of char*, as  std::string is a cleaner, safer way to go because it removes the burden of memory management from the programmer.

Have a look at the working implementation, without use of const:

```
#include <string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct PET
{ 
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

bool compare(const struct PET& a, const struct PET& b){

    return (a.name.compare(b.name) <= 0) ? true : false;        
}

int main(){

    std::vector<struct PET> vec(3);

    vec[0].name = "dog";
    vec[0].age = 3;

    vec[1].name = "cat";
    vec[1].age = 1;

    vec[2].name = "bird";
    vec[2].age = 2;

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), compare);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

        std::cout<<vec[i].name<<" "<<vec[i].age<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Deepak Tatyaji Ahire and @Ulrich Eckhardt said, you can't do what you wrote in your code.

`const int` can't be a variable. It is a constant for definition :)

The vector you wrote in your code can't be built that way.
I did not understand what you wanted to do with the "sort" function, I wrote the following to code, maybe it could help:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

struct PET
{
 const char* pet;
 int age;

 PET(const char* c, int a) : pet(c) , age(a) {}

};

void  Foo(PET &p, std::vector<PET> &v)
{
  v.push_back(p);
  /*do something here if needed*/

}

int main()
{
    std::vector<PET> vect;
    PET cat("Cat", 5);
    PET dog("Dog", 10);
    PET bird("Bird", 2);
    Foo(cat, vect);
    Foo(dog, vect);
    Foo(bird, vect);
    /*this is not elegant, you could define a function that give a list of
    ({Animal, age},...) to vector and then pushes back all these elements to the vector*/
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) std::cout<< vect[i].pet << ' ' << vect[i].age << std::endl; //std::cout << vect; if you are using an operator << overload
    /*to overload the << operator in order to able to print the vector of struct PET:

std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, std::vector<PET> &p)
{
     os << "<";
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        os << p[i].pet;
        os << ", ";
        os << p[i].age;
        if (i != p.size() - 1)
            os << " - ";
    }
    os << ">\n";
    return os;
}

    */

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, there's no way to directly compare structures without defining their comparator.

Though in C++20, it introduces three-way comparison and you might be allowed to declare the [Default comparisons](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) by a single line. Very convenient. Unfortunately, there haven been no compiler implementing this feature.

For now, you have to manually define the comparator

```
inline bool cmp(const PET &lhs, const PET &rhs)
{
    return std::strcmp(lhs.pet, rhs.pet)<0;
}
```

and pass it to `std::sort`

Comment: Strongly agree with @Mark Taylor, it's really confusing to edit the original question. Maybe appending the new content will be a better choice.